# How do I center the button

Tags: html, css

An image of the web page:
[image: Web page image]

I want to put the button in the middle of the first box. I have followed a [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_center_button.asp) from w3 schools  but it puts the button in the middle of webpage instead of putting it in the middle of the first box.

My code:

```css
.menus{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.menu{
    background-color: orange;
    border: 3px solid grey;
    width: 98vh;
    height: 98vh;
}

.menu1{
    min-height: 50px;
}

.menu2{
    min-height: 50px;
}

.menu1 h1{
    magin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="menus">

            <!-- program -->
            <div class="menu menu1">
                <h1></h1>
                    <button>button</button>
            </div>

            <!-- items -->
            <div class="menu menu2"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: use `text-align: center` in `.menu1`

Answer (score -1):

Add flexbox-settings as shown below to `.menu1`. This will center *all* contents of `.menu1`(alternative solution below):

```css
.menus{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.menu{
    background-color: orange;
    border: 3px solid grey;
    width: 98vh;
    height: 98vh;
}

.menu1{
    min-height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.menu2{
    min-height: 50px;
}

.menu1 h1{
    magin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="menus">

            <!-- program -->
            <div class="menu menu1">
                <h1></h1>
                    <button>button</button>
            </div>

            <!-- items -->
            <div class="menu menu2"></div>
            </div>
```

Second solution added after comment, which only centers `button`, but leaves other contents of `.menu1` as is.

Note the settings for `.menu1` and `.menu1 button`.

```css
.menus {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.menu {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  width: 98vh;
  height: 98vh;
}

.menu1 {
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu1 button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.menu2 {
  min-height: 50px;
}

.menu1 h1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="menus">

  <!-- program -->
  <div class="menu menu1">
    <h1></h1>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>

  <!-- items -->
  <div class="menu menu2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I do this everything I put in menu1 gets centered. I only want to center the button

Comment: I added a second solution which does what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Flexbox in your `.menu1` class.

```css
.menus{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.menu{
    background-color: orange;
    border: 3px solid grey;
    width: 98vh;
    height: 98vh;
}

.menu1{
    min-height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu2{
    min-height: 50px;
}

.menu1 h1{
    magin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="menus">

            <!-- program -->
            <div class="menu menu1">
                <h1></h1>
                    <button>button</button>
            </div>

            <!-- items -->
            <div class="menu menu2"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .center-div {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .parent{
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background: #555
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="center-div parent">
    <button>button</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```